# Making web servlets on Debian 10 with Java EE

Tags: debian, java

Doesn't seem like Java EE exists in the repository. It's non-free right...? Well I found a download link on oracle's website but it's 135MB and I'm on a slow connection now and I don't think I need that much, I'm only gonna make a very simple servlet. Am I out cycling? Should I be using php instead? It's just that I'm already familiar with java and servlets, and I don't want to learn php.

EDIT:
Just thought I'd post where things stopped working.

```
javac FormHandlerServlet.java 
FormHandlerServlet.java:4: error: package javax.servlet does not    exist
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
                    ^
```

So I want to download this and other packages which I guess is included in Java EE? I did download Java EE but idk how to get the packages in the right place.

Comment: OpenJDK is in the Debian repos, but is not lighter. Depending on what you are trying to do, Python, Perl, Ruby, Bash are alternatives and may already be installed.

Comment: Thank you! Already have OpenJDK, but that doesn't include java ee as far as i'm aware? Hm yes, I have a little experience with Ruby and Python, could try that. Thanks again.